# What is the right use for each expression?

Tags: expressions, prepositions

- You can call me at my cell phone.
- You can call me on my cell phone.
- You can call me from my cell phone.
- You can call me via my cell phone.

What are the differences among them?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well I think only 2 of those would ever really be used properly. Call me on my cell phone and call me from my cell phone. The latter assuming you gave someone your cell phone and a different number to reach you. Via my cell phone is kinda of OK but it just sounds bad and doesn't really use the best words to maintain clarity. Call me at my cell phone might be a British thing, or some other colloquialism from another country. Still, it sounds like garbage and comes across as if it is being said by someone for whom English is a second language.